# Java, gravar em uma linha específica de um arquivo .txt

Tags: java, txt

estive testando vários modos de escrever os dados de uma variável em um arquivo de texto(.txt), porém preciso saber se tem como escrever esta variável em uma determinada linha, assim eu poderia organizar vários dados no mesmo arquivo manipulando somente a linha desejada.

```
package geraclube;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import static java.nio.file.Files.lines;
import static java.nio.file.Files.lines;
import static java.nio.file.Files.lines;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Start {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    MoneyGenerator gerM = new MoneyGenerator(); // instancia o gerador de dinheiro

    String saveLoadFile = "dados_java.txt";

    // puxa os dados do arquivo "dados_java.txt", vai puxar os arquivos da Linha 1
    // observem que os itens estão descritos com dois pontos duplos para facilitar...
    //...a identificação dos campos e o split a baixo.
    String moneyLine = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(saveLoadFile)).get(1);
    String[] parts = moneyLine.split("::");

    //após o split vai separar somente o número real para o código
    int saldoFinal = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

    // se o saldo for zero o código vai gerar...
    //...um novo valor através da classe MoneyGenerator.java
    if (saldoFinal == 0) {
        saldoFinal = (gerM.clubMoney);


    }
    System.out.println(saldoFinal);

}
```

Caso caia no "if" eu gostaria de gravar o resultado da variável na segunda linha de um arquivo .txt sem alterar as demais linhas. É possível? Ou eu teria de utilizar outro método?

Answer (score 2):

Não tenho certeza se é possível atualizar somente uma linha já escrita dentro de um arquivo txt, o que você pode fazer como alternativa é atualizar o conteúdo completo do arquivo, segue o exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

MoneyGenerator gerM = new MoneyGenerator(); // instancia o gerador de dinheiro

String saveLoadFile = "dados_java.txt";

File file = new File(saveLoadFile);

//Salvando todas as linhas do arquivo na memória
List<String> moneyLines= Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(saveLoadFile));
//pegando informação da linha 2
String linha2 = moneyLines.get(1);

//Split da linha
String[] parts = linha2.split("::");

//após o split vai separar somente o número real para o código
int saldoFinal = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
//deletando o conteúdo do arquivo
deletarConteudoTxt(file);

// se o saldo for zero o código vai gerar...
//...um novo valor através da classe MoneyGenerator.java
if (saldoFinal == 0) {
    saldoFinal = (gerM.clubMoney);
    //alterando o valor da segunda linha
    String conteudo =parts[0]+"::"+parts[1];
    moneyLines.set(1,conteudo);

}
//Escrevendo o novo conteúdo no arquivo txt.
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
for(int i=0; i<moneyLines.size(); i++){
    writer.println(moneyLines.get(i));

}
writer.close();

public static void deletarConteudoTxt(File file) throws FileNotFoundException{
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
    writer.close();
}
```